# Intellij: How to hot swap the external libraries (Multi module maven)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

Just started exploring Intellij features and was wondering how we do this?

We have multi module maven projects with Spring MVC upto 3 levels

i.e we have a parent maven multi module projects Say A, Say B and my final multi module project which we run is Say C

We have dependencies and overlays setup in such a way that C uses or overlays the artifacts from A and B

When running C, Iam getting all my dependencies from A and B as external libraries. Now I wish to do changes in A and B and wish to see that changes in C (Another window on Intellij) automatically.

How can I get it ?

Please Note: At the moment I need to do maven build on A and then B and then on C to see the changes pushed to my Tomcat server.

If I just build A or B, my intelliJ editor sees the changes but that changes are not flowing to the tomcat untill i build C

Any help around would be great ?

PS: IN eclipse i use to have all the projects A and B and C in single window and when I deploy C, Eclipse used to automatically identify the artifacts that are open from A and B and links to that directly.

Iam hoping there should be something equivalent in intellij.So.. please ?